# Protractor suite option won't run any test

Tags: protractor

I read somewhere that protractor can specify suite option in its configuration file, I used something like

```
suites: {
homepage: 'test/e2e/homepage/*.js'
},
```

Then I run the suite with:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --suite homepage
```

or

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --suite=homepage
```

But both didn't run any test, and say:
0 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: If your run protractor with `--specs='test/e2e/homepage/*.js'` does it works?

Comment: It works if I use --specs=test/e2e/homepage/*.js (without the '' in your example)

Comment: If I use specs:[...] in config file it also runs, but the point is to use suites option in config file, that doesn't work for me

Comment: I would try adding `[]` to see if that helps: `homepage: ['test/e2e/homepage/*.js']` and other thing would be adding the absolute path. Also if you could link a gist to your full config file, there might be something else going on here.

Comment: I figured the 'suite' is missing a 's' at the end. But now if I try:protractor protractor.conf.js --suites homepage, I got a bunch of warnings before tests run and finish:Warning: pattern h did not match any files.
Warning: pattern o did not match any files.
Warning: pattern m did not match any files.
Warning: pattern e did not match any files.
Warning: pattern p did not match any files.
Warning: pattern a did not match any files.
Warning: pattern g did not match any files.

Comment: I removed homepage after --suites and now the warning is gone too.

Comment: The param is `--suite` for sure. And in the config is `suites`. What version of Protractor are you using?

Comment: Look: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/scripts/test.js#L20

Comment: And: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/suitesConf.js#L7

Comment: I'm using protractor Version 1.0.0-rc4

Comment: You could try to upgrade, that's a previous version: https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases

Comment: I updated to the latest, now --suite is working. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have a similar issue --suites=foo , if I don't use the --suites all the assertions are executed with --suites no assertions after the promise is executed.

Comment: There seems to be a difference in the way paths behave between `suite` and `specs`. It seems like `--suite` is executed from the same path as the `protractor.conf` file, whereas `--spec` runs from the `CWD` (current working directory).

Answer (score 2):

Makes sure the path `suite` is relative to the `protractor.conf` file. For example with the directory structure like this:

```
├── app
│   └── test1.e2e.js
│   └── test2.e2e.js
├── test
│   └── protractor-conf.js
```

Your `protractor.conf` should look like this:

```
suites: {
  mySuite: [

    // The suite path is relative to the protractor.conf file
    '../app/*.e2e.js'
  ],
},
```

This is different from `spec`, which uses paths relative to the CWD from which protractor is run:

```
// Assuming you run tests from parent dir of `app`
specs: [
  'app/test1.e2e.js'
  'app/test2.e2e.js'
],
```